# Cell size not changed in collection view IOS (Implemented in Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that needs to have the cells fitting size to content.
I use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to set size for each cell.
It's fired and works great.

Here is the problem what I am facing.
The data list for collection view is changed dynamically.

- collection view has only 1 item to show and shows it in correct cell size(let's say **size1**)
- next time collection view has 1 item to show again but it's different data.

In this case, the collection view doesn't show it in correct cell size. it shows in **size1**
I want to show next item in its own size but collection view keep original size.
When item count is changed, `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` is fired again.
When item count is same, it's not fired.

I want it to be fired everytime.

I share some of my code.

```
cllSelected.Source = new SelectedItemSource(this, _selectedItems);
```

Above code will be called whenever there is new `_selectedItems`

I implemented the `UICollectionViewSource` as following

```
public class SelectedItemSource : UICollectionViewSource, IUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
    {
        CatalogVC _ownerVC;
        SelectedCategoryList _selectedItems;

        public SelectedItemSource(CatalogVC ownerVC, SelectedCategoryList selectedItems)
        {
            _ownerVC = ownerVC;
            _selectedItems = selectedItems;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return _selectedItems != null ? _selectedItems.Count : 0;
        }

        public override bool ShouldHighlightItem(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void ItemHighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

        }

        public override void ItemUnhighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            _ownerVC.SelectedFilter_ItemClick(indexPath.Row);
        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            SelectedFilterCollectionCell cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("SelectedFilterCollectionCell", indexPath) as SelectedFilterCollectionCell;
            cell.Layer.ShouldRasterize = true;
            cell.Layer.RasterizationScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;

            cell.BindDataToCell(_selectedItems[indexPath.Row]);

            return cell;
        }

        [Export("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:")]
        public CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var text = new NSString(_selectedItems[indexPath.Row].Text);
            CGSize cellSize = new CGSize(xxx, yyy); // cellSize will be determined according to text

            return cellSize;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any solution or suggestion!

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @ChandreshKachariya Shared my code.

Comment: Let try with set dataSource And delegate programmatically

Comment: solve a problem?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. As I described, it works good but doesn't work in some case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `CollectionView.ReloadData()`  after the data changes.

I think it will invoke the methods included in the delegate.